# Htaccess url multilanguage

Tags: php, .htaccess

I would like the language accepted by the browser to be automatically added via htaccess. Guy

www.test.com/en/
www.test.com/ru/

My problem is that I have href of this type:

"/user/sign-up"

"/CEO/register"

etc..

I use a php file to do the routes:

```
case '/user/sign-up':   
    require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'app/SignUp.php';
    break;
```

etc...

The urls are all without the language, that is: www.test.com/ceo/register

I only have two languages ​​that I accept ru and en. Also if the user changes the language I save the setting inside a session

Do you know how I can do it?

Comment: so actual url is www.test.com/ru/CEO/register ??

Comment: The urls are all without the language, that is:

www.test.com/ceo/register

the translation takes place but I would like to automatically set the language before after the domain www.test.com/en/ceo/register without having to change all the urls